# Uninstall an MSI with msiexec fails with new version of MSI

Tags: installation, continuous-integration, windows-installer

We are installing several web sites using msi's as part of continuos integration tests.

For each build we want to uninstall the old msi and install a new one.

Problem is we do not have the old msi after the build server has done a get latest and rebuilt the system.

Is there a way in which we can uninstall the msi without having access to the orginal msi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can, if you know the product code. Just type

```
msiexec /x [ProductCode]
```

on the command line. Or you could do it through the Add/Remove programs applet.

If you want to find the physical file, Windows actually stores a copy of the msi when it runs it - you will find it somewhere in your %WINDOWS%\Installer folder, but it will have been given a random name so could be quite hard to find :)
Alternatively if you don't know the product code (which you should) then try searching for your app name under the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Installer` and `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData` registry keys, you will find the product code there. (quick hint: you can also search for `UninstallString` values in the registry).